# C# and the <module></module> tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, module

I've never run into this before. We have a .cshtml file, and within it is a DIV that contains some bootstrap styling and the following:

```
<div class="rStart hidden-xs col-sm-12 rEnd product-content-module product-grid-module">
<module name="ProductGridView">
    @json
</module>
```

The contents of @json aren't really important. What's puzzling me is where I need to look for "`ProductGridView`". I've searched our entire solution, and it only turns up in this one file. It's relevant, because a similar construct is used elsewhere in the solution, and I can't find where those "modules" are, either.

We're using VS2015, and we are not using .NET core. I believe we're using .NET 4.5.

Has anyone ever used these `<module>` tags before?

Comment: that's basically a custom tag that has no official defined meaning. you can use <deadbeef></deadbeef> tag for the same effect

Comment: So what about the actual name of the module? I would assume that means something in this context. Or is it just a generic tag name (i.e. "myTag")? If that's the case, then I just need to focus on the @model of the page, and the ViewModel that we're using. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Is it required by some third party javascript you're using? That might be why you don't find it by searching the project if its pulled in via CDN.

Comment: @MJR as I said. it has no official meaning. So any JS library can treat it any way they want.

Comment: @Steve Gotcha. I think we figured out what was going on...